# Can't fint specific element from mysql's array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

so i have a small problem. i want to save data from mysql into an array and then i want to search a specific word in that array and retrieve if was found or not, i've tried in so many ways, and still no success.It always retrieve "word not found". I've tried too with array_search and with a for loop. what am i missing?

```
<?php

include("conn.php");
$keyword = "universidade";

$row = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT keywords FROM beta_universidades");

while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $row[] = $data;
}

echo "<br><br>";

$chave = in_array($keyword, $row);

if ($chave !== false) {
    echo "word found";
} else {
    echo "word not found";
}
```

Comment: Why not have the DB search for the term? `SELECT keywords FROM beta_universidades where keywords = '$escaped_var'`, or use a `like`. You also should update your driver so you can use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use key `'keywords'` with your `$data` array..

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $row[] = $data['keywords']; 
}
```

Comment: it worked, but why is it needed the 'keywords'  if i put in the mysql query

Comment: because [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) does not works for multidimensional array, so that why we use `$data['keywords']` and push only keywords value into `$row` instead of full `$data` array... @eternaty

Comment: you can accept and up vote the helpful answers ... :) @eternaty

Answer (score 1):

In your case `$row` is an array of arrays so you should try something like:

```
foreach ($row as $myKeywords) {
   $chave = in_array($keyword, $myKeywords['keywords']);

   if ($chave !== false) {
      echo "word found";
      break;
   }
}
```